# Getting java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06530: Reference to uninitialized composite when Calling PLSQL stored procedure from JPA

Tags: java, oracle, jpa

Here is my JPA code which fails to execute with error in topic header.

```
@Override
public void validateVelocityRules(long organizationId, long accountId, long userId, Map<Integer, VelocityRuleChecker> rulesById, BigDecimal depositAmount, int depositItemCount) {
    List<VelocityScrutinyRuleRec> velocityScrutinyRuleTab = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Integer ruleId : rulesById.keySet()) {
        VelocityScrutinyRuleRec velocityScrutinyRuleRec = new VelocityScrutinyRuleRec();
        velocityScrutinyRuleRec.setId(ruleId);
        velocityScrutinyRuleRec.setIsFailed(null);
        velocityScrutinyRuleTab.add(velocityScrutinyRuleRec);
    }

    PLSQLrecord record = new PLSQLrecord();
    record.setTypeName("VELOCITY_SCRUTINY_RULES_REC");
    record.setCompatibleType("VELOCITY_SCRUTINY_RULES_REC");
    record.setJavaType(VelocityScrutinyRuleRec.class);
    record.addField("ID", JDBCTypes.NUMERIC_TYPE, 20,0);
    record.addField("IS_FAILED", JDBCTypes.CHAR_TYPE, 1);

    PLSQLCollection collection = new PLSQLCollection();
    collection.setTypeName("VELOCITY_SCRUTINY_RULES_TAB");
    collection.setCompatibleType("VELOCITY_SCRUTINY_RULES_TAB");
    collection.setJavaType(List.class);
    collection.setNestedType(record);

    PLSQLStoredProcedureCall call = new PLSQLStoredProcedureCall();
    call.setProcedureName("VELOCITY_PKG.SP_VALIDATE_RULES");
    call.addNamedArgument("p_org_id", JDBCTypes.INTEGER_TYPE);
```

.
.
.
.        call.addNamedInOutputArgument("p_rule", collection,JDBCTypes.ARRAY_TYPE.getSqlCode());

```
    DataReadQuery dataReadQuery = new DataReadQuery(call);

    dataReadQuery.addArgument("p_org_id");
    dataReadQuery.addArgument("p_rule", List.class);

    Vector args = new Vector();
    args.add(organizationId);
    args.add(velocityScrutinyRuleTab);

    ServerSession session =
            ((JpaEntityManager)entityManager.getDelegate()).getServerSession();

    ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor descriptor = new ObjectRelationalDataTypeDescriptor();
    descriptor.setJavaClass(VelocityScrutinyRuleRec.class);
    descriptor.setTableName("VELOCITY_SCRUTINY_RULES_REC");
    descriptor.setStructureName("VELOCITY_SCRUTINY_RULES_REC");
    descriptor.setPrimaryKeyFieldName("ID");
    descriptor.addFieldOrdering("ID");
    descriptor.addFieldOrdering("IS_FAILED");

    descriptor.addDirectMapping("id", "ID");
    descriptor.addDirectMapping("isFailed", "IS_FAILED");
    session.addDescriptor(descriptor);
    Object object = JpaHelper.getEntityManager(entityManager).getActiveSession().executeQuery(dataReadQuery, args);
```

This code call a stored procedure with definition that takes following OBJECT TYPE as IN and OUT argument.

Comment: This should be coming from DB internals. may be stored procedure have it's own error. Did you try to run it without JPA - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_06530_reference_to_uninitialized_composite.htm

Comment: Yes. This stored procedure has been around for few years. We started getting this error as we started using JPA. The last argument of SP is a table of an oracle object type. Do I need any special treatment for it such as descriptor apart from PLSQLCollection I already created.

Comment: Another thing to note is that it is being thrown from the plsql code shown in stacktrace. It is JPA created code. Looks like it is not getting the last argument which is a plsql table.